# Continuous crawling

Tags: sharepoint-server, search-results, enterprise-search, crawling

We have SP 2016 site with continuous crawling enabled for SP content source.

Randomly we find Search will miss out on crawling some items

The users then update the item again and it magically works and appears in search results.

Anyone experienced anything similar ?

Comment: If your have access to the Central Admin, you may verify if the particular document was successfully crawled or not. Search Administration=>Crawl Log =>URL view and provide the URL to check if there were any error or it crawled successfully. Then decide the next step

Answer (score 0):

Sometime miss crawl some items is a normal behavior.

Continuous crawls crawl SharePoint Server sites frequently to help keep search results fresh. Like incremental crawls, a continuous crawl crawls content that was added, changed, or deleted since the last crawl.

Continuous crawls are especially useful for crawling SharePoint Server content that is quickly changing.

Manage continuous crawls in SharePoint Server for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/manage-continuous-crawls

Comment: Lisa Is it normal behaviour for incremental crawls too ?

Comment: Yes, it is normal behaviour for incremental crawls too.

Comment: Thanks again Lisa. Is there any way to ensure items are not missed out. Any config changes etc

Comment: Generally speaking, it will not miss out items, there are occasional minor problems.
you don't need to change any config.